# Text in Eclipse Editor Blurry

Tags: fonts, eclipse

I recently upgraded my home monitor to a 1440p.  Everything now looks sharper -- except Eclipse...   For some reason, the fonts on eclipse are blurred (whereas the title bar on the same window is perfectly crisp) -- picture to demonstrate:

[image: Fuzzy Font on Eclipse]

Unfortunately, while I can still make out the text, I can't unsee the issue, and it bothers me to no end...  I tried playing with the Windows 10  'size and layout' settings, moving between 100% and 150%, but it doesn't seem to fix it.   I'm not sure where in eclipse I would set the monitor resolution or render settings.   I'm wondering if anyone knows how to fix this?